# Download a file when working with .NET Core Web API (Calling Third Party API) and Angular 13

Tags: c#, angular, rest, asp.net-core, blob

I have an API Method calling a third party API and sending binary data for a file with the extension **.gz**. I am just calling the third party API and sending an HttpResponseMessage back to my Angular code.

Below is my API Service code

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadGzippedFile(string segment, string folderPath, string fileName, string token)
{
  using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
  {

          // NOTE: accept all media types
          httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
                try
                {
                    var fileUrl = $"{uri}member/file/download/1.0?segment=" + segment + "&folderPath=" + folderPath + "&filename=" + fileName;
                    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl);
                    
                    string value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return response;
                    else
                        throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return null;
                }
  }
}
```

*And Angular 13 Type Script Code*

- **Service**

```
download(segment:string,folderPath:string,fileName:string) :Observable<Blob> {
    folderPath='/'+folderPath.slice(0,folderPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    const url = 'http://localhost:22721/api/NseDownload/DownloadGzippedFile?segment='+segment+'&folderPath='+folderPath+'&fileName='+fileName+'&token='+localStorage.getItem("token");
    return this.http.get(url,{ responseType: 'blob'  });
  }
```

- **Component**
- *NOTE* : import {  saveAs  } from "file-saver";

```
download(node:any){
this.db.download('CM',node.folderPath,node.name).subscribe(response=>{
saveAs(response, node.name) 
})
}
```

- *PROBLEM*: My response is not getting binary Data. Instead I am getting this response below:

```
{"version":"1.1","content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["attachment; filename=\"07765_C_member_missing_client_details.csv.gz\""]},{"key":"Expires","value":["Mon, 20 Feb 2023 10:19:19 GMT"]},{"key":"Content-Length","value":["39968"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[{"key":"Vary","value":["Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers"]},{"key":"X-Frame-Options","value":["SAMEORIGIN"]},{"key":"X-XSS-Protection","value":["1; mode=block"]},{"key":"X-Forwarded-Proto","value":["https"]},{"key":"X-Content-Type","value":["nosniff"]},{"key":"Strict-Transport-Security","value":["max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload"]},{"key":"Cache-Control","value":["no-store, no-cache, max-age=0"]},{"key":"Pragma","value":["no-cache"]},{"key":"Date","value":["Mon, 20 Feb 2023 10:19:19 GMT"]},{"key":"Connection","value":["keep-alive"]},{"key":"Set-Cookie","value":["HttpOnly; Secure"]}],"trailingHeaders":[],"requestMessage":{"version":"1.1","versionPolicy":0,"content":null,"method":{"method":"GET"},"requestUri":"{uri}/member/file/download/1.0?segment=CM&folderPath=/Reports&filename=07765_details.csv.gz","headers":[{"key":"Accept","value":["*/*"]},{"key":"Authorization","value":["Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJtZW1iZXJDNSwiaWF0IjoxNjc2ODg4MzA1LCJqdGkiOiIzY2UzMGJjMy0yY2M4LTRjZDEtOWIyMy1jOWY0ZDEwMDgxOTgifQ.Dfn-G4US36sO3F1ekNhQZWk6J8uXH_PBaQGGGwevsNMncZgk4zUUJaC1peFqO9mCBy1UFmyO9ngw-YAP_aEzNg"]},{"key":"traceparent","value":["00-b76ec4bd3d634170ef8bce99e991ce57-76cf6e6800e6d661-00"]}],"properties":{},"options":{}},"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how got my solution
API Code :

- Service

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadGzippedFile(string segment, string folderPath, string fileName, string token)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {

                // NOTE: accept all media types
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
                try
                {
                    var fileUrl = $"{uri}member/file/download/1.0?segment=" + segment + "&folderPath=" + folderPath + "&filename=" + fileName;
                    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl);
                    
                    string value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return response;
                    else
                        throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

- Controller

```
     [HttpGet, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(byte[]), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(BadRequestObjectResult), 400)]
        [Route("DownloadGzippedFile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadGzippedFile(string segment, string folderPath, string fileName, string token)
        {
            var httpRespMsg = await _nSEDownload.DownloadGzippedFile(segment, folderPath, fileName, token);
            return File(await httpRespMsg.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), "application/octet-stream", fileName);
            ;
        }
```

- Angular Code
- Service

```
    download(segment:string,folderPath:string,fileName:string) :Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    folderPath='/'+folderPath.slice(0,folderPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    const url = 'http://localhost:22721/api/NseDownload/DownloadGzippedFile?segment='+segment+'&folderPath='+folderPath+'&fileName='+fileName+'&token='+localStorage.getItem("token");
    return this.http.get(url,
      { observe:'response', responseType: 'blob'  });
  }
```

- Component

```
    download(node:any){
    this.db.download('CM',node.folderPath,node.name).subscribe(response=>{
      var blob = response.body as Blob;
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = node.name;
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    })
```

I hope this will help other. Enjoy Programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Your api return type should be

```
Task<IActionResult>.
```

Then you could do :

```
return new FileStreamResult(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), "application/gzip");
```